# Modulo operator in Pascal?

Tags: pascal

How can I get the leftover of dividing 2 `int`s?

When using Java I use the `%` operator, but what can I do in Pascal?

Answer (score 6):

Use mod operator as described here. http://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_operators.htm

```
A mod B
```

Comment: Please describe it here. Your answer loses all meaning if most of the content is on an off-site location and that site is unavailable for some reason (it's moved, off-line, etc.). Answers should contain enough content to answer the question here; links to external sites should be used as additional references only. Thanks.

Comment: Note that the tutorial on tutorialspoint.com said `%` (percent sign) is the modulo operator. It might be a wrong input, I guess. See also [Pascal - Arithmetic Operators (tutorialspoint.com)](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pascal/pascal_arithmetic_operators.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Pascal's `modulo` operator is `mod`. It works just like the `%` operator in Java and C/C++:

```
var
  X, Y: Integer;
begin
  X := 10;
  Y := X mod 4;  // result: Y = 2
  Y := X mod 3;  // result: Y = 1
end;
```

Comment: Also be aware that `div` and `mod` are integer versions of division/modulo, while `/` returns a real result.

Comment: The poster specified "leftover of dividing 2 `ints`, but it probably should be pointed out for future readers. Thanks. :-) (Modulo operations are always integer and therefore result in integer values.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `n mod 2` the same way you'd use `n % 2` in Java (when `n>=0` anyway...not sure what Pascal does with negative numbers, but Java does the wrong thing.)

However, the most common reason for doing that is to test whether the number is even or odd, and Pascal has the built-in function `odd(n)` to do just that.  On many compilers `ord(odd(n))` is a faster way to get the remainder of n mod 2.

Answer (score 1):

Regrettably Pascal mod cannot be used that way. The reason is that I did an incomplete job cajoling the Pascal standards committee.

I lobbied and begged the standards committee to do mod the right way until eventually they relented. So, for example -5 mod 2 equals 1.  To my horror, they did integer division the wrong way. I never imagined they would not make the two match up. To this day, in Pascal (-5 mod 2) + (-5 / 2) equals -4.  I blame myself.

Comment: Thumbs up for trying.  That last bit, though...did you mean (-5 mod 2) + (-5 div 2)*2?  I wouldn't expect (a mod b) + (a / b) to be anything special, but you'd like (a mod b) + (a div b)*b to get back to a.  (And I get -3 and not -4 from that.)

Answer (score 0):

In delphi there is the MOD operator aka   x = Y MOD Z. should work in pascal